# Automating Word to insert an image from a URL

Tags: automation, ms-word, javascript

from Automation in jscript how can I programatically insert an image into Word (2000+) from a URL?

The url also is quite long, around 400 characters, and I've read that Word 2007 has a problem sometimes with strings longer than 255 characters.

I've used this successfully except that it won't allow urls longer than 255 characters:

```
    var oDialog = oWordDoc.Application.Dialogs( wdDialogInsertPicture );
    oDialog.Name = imageUrl;
    oDialog.LinkToFile = false;
    oDialog.FloatOverText = true;
    oDialog.Execute();
```

Comment: Note exactly the answer you're looking for, but could you feed the url to a url shortening service first?

Comment: I couldn't sorry as it's a secure url for an intranet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a > 255 char url to test it with, but try this:

```
oWordDoc.Shapes.AddPicture(imageUrl, false);
```

Comment: Great that works. My remaining problem is that now the image comes out of my table cell it was in. I was using oDialog.FloatOverText = true; before to stop this. Do you know what the equivalent Shapes parameter is?

Comment: It should be floating over text by default.  Maybe it is just anchored to the wrong part of the document?  A "Shape" is floating and an "InlineShape" is not.  Both classes have "ConvertTox" functions to convert to the other.